# Displaying links on columns mapped to custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

Say I have **Course** that has_many **Students**.  I also have **def top_student** in the Course class.  I now have an active_scaffold on top of **Course**, but if I add **top_student** as a column it show shows #, but no link.  I'd like a link to the Student who is the Top Student.  Any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Class method
  def self.top_student
    # Some logic
  end
end
```

it should be:

```
<%=link_to "Top Student", Course.top_student %>
```